# Class loading for Flink Kafka Source Timestamp Extractor

Tags: scala, classpath, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to deploy a Flink job to a cluster based on the **flink:1.4.1-hadoop27-scala_2.11-alpine** image. The job is using a Kafka connector source (flink-connector-kafka-0.11) to which I'm trying to assign timestamps and watermarks. My code is very similar to the Scala example in the [Flink Kafka connector documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-and-timestamp-extractionwatermark-emission). But with FlinkKafkaConsumer011

```
val myConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer08[String]("topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)
myConsumer.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new CustomWatermarkEmitter())
```

This works great when running locally from my IDE. However, in the cluster envrionment I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.organization.CustomWatermarkEmitter
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil$ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(InstantiationUtil.java:73)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1863)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1746)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2037)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1568)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:428)
at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:393)
at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:380)
at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:368)
at org.apache.flink.util.SerializedValue.deserializeValue(SerializedValue.java:58)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractFetcher.createPartitionStateHolders(AbstractFetcher.java:521)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractFetcher.<init>(AbstractFetcher.java:167)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka09Fetcher.<init>(Kafka09Fetcher.java:89)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka010Fetcher.<init>(Kafka010Fetcher.java:62)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer010.createFetcher(FlinkKafkaConsumer010.java:203)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:564)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:86)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:55)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:94)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:264)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm building my job as a fat jar which I have verified contains this class. 
**Does this example from the documentation only work if the CustomWatermarkEmitter class is in the /opt/flink/lib/ folder?**

This is the way I had to solve the issue. But having to build this class separately and placing it in /opt/flink/lib complicates my build process significantly so I was wondering if this is the way it's supposed to be solved or if there are other ways around this problem?

For example this section in the [Flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html#manual-classloading-in-the-job) hints at having to provide some sources a UserCodeClassLoader manually? Including the provided Kafka source?

It seems to use a "userCodeClassLoader" internally as far as I could see in org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractFetcher:

```
            case PERIODIC_WATERMARKS: {
            for (Map.Entry<KafkaTopicPartition, Long> partitionEntry : partitionsToInitialOffsets.entrySet()) {
                KPH kafkaHandle = createKafkaPartitionHandle(partitionEntry.getKey());

                AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<T> assignerInstance =
                        watermarksPeriodic.deserializeValue(userCodeClassLoader);

                KafkaTopicPartitionStateWithPeriodicWatermarks<T, KPH> partitionState =
                        new KafkaTopicPartitionStateWithPeriodicWatermarks<>(
                                partitionEntry.getKey(),
                                kafkaHandle,
                                assignerInstance);

                partitionState.setOffset(partitionEntry.getValue());

                partitionStates.add(partitionState);
            }
```

**EDIT:**

I have created a simple project where this issue can be reprodued here:
https://github.com/lragnarsson/flink-kafka-classpath-problem

In order to reproduce, you need docker and docker-compose.

just do:

1. git clone https://github.com/lragnarsson/flink-kafka-classpath-problem.git
2. cd flink-kafka-classpath-problem/docker
3. docker-compose build
4. docker-compose up
5. Go to localhost:8081 in your browser
6. Submit included jar file from target/scala-2.11/flink-kafka-classpath-problem-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

This should lead to the exception **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: se.ragnarsson.lage.MyTimestampExtractor**

Comment: Are you able to put a sanitized version of your actual code? I've successfully done this exact thing with no issues (Flink 1.4, Kafka 0.11 connector, source-based timestamps), so the issue may be subtle.

Comment: I will try to prepare a minimal example. Did you deploy in a docker container? I'm running it with one taskmanager container and one jobmanager under Kubernetes, similar to this: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/deployment/kubernetes.html

Comment: @JoshuaDeWald I have edited the original post with an example project which reproduces this problem.

Comment: Nice! Based on everything here, it seems like you stumbled on a bug where perhaps the the Kafka connector is using the global Flink classloader (essentially, parent-only) rather than the user classloader that it itself has been loaded from. I misspoke above about having done the same thing, as I in fact used one of the built-in extractors, which would have been loaded from the main classloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've stumbled on a bug introduced in Flink 1.4.1: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-8741.

It will be fixed shortly in 1.4.2. You can try to test in on the 1.4.2.rc2:https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/release-1.4.2-rc2

Comment: Thank you! Odd that I didn't find that Jira issue when troubleshooting.